# Difference between JPAQuery and JPAQueryFactory

Tags: jpa, querydsl

What is the difference between JPAQuery and JPAQueryFactory?
And, When to use which?

According to the querydsl reference documentation:

> **Both JPAQuery and HibernateQuery implement the JPQLQuery interface.**
>
> **For the examples of this chapter the queries are created via a JPAQueryFactory instance. JPAQueryFactory should be the preferred
> option to obtain JPAQuery instances.**

But, I could not understand clearly.
Can anyone explain it briefly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What matters is that Hibernates query language (HQL) is a superset of JPA's query language (JPQL). Hibernate also has a special method for result set transformation and being able to iterate over scrollable result sets without the need to keep a reference to all records in memory. In order to take advantage of this extra functionality, the `HQLTemplates` and the `HibernateHandler` have to be used. The first is responsible for serializing the additional types of expressions, the second for the integration with Hibernates `Query` implementation. The `HibernateHandler` is actually obtained from the `HQLTemplates` as well, so all that remains is specifying `HQLTemplates`.

And in fact: a `JPAQuery` instantiated with `HQLTemplates.INSTANCE` for the `Templates` variable, behaves the same as a `HibernateQuery`. FWIW, if you provide an `EntityManager` instance with the construction of your `JPAQuery`, then the appropriate implementation for `Templates` is deduced for your ORM vendor automatically.

All `JPAQueryFactory` really is, is a factory method that binds the `EntityManager` and `Templates` variables for newly instantiated `JPAQueries`. This eliminates the need to pass these as a variable individually for each instantiation of a `JPAQuery`.

There is no need to use the `JPAQueryFactory`, but it could make your code easier to read. Furthermore, a lot of code examples on the QueryDSL website utilize the query factory, so it might make it easier to use these examples as snippets in your own code.

Comment: "There is no need to use the `JPAQueryFactory`, but it could make your code easier to read": this statement is quite a bit weaker than the doc quoted by OP ("JPAQueryFactory should be the preferred option to obtain JPAQuery instances.").  I have to admit being confused by that statement too.  Another issue: the javadoc for `JPAQueryFactory` doesn't mention if creating new instances ad-lib is detrimental.  I love QueryDSL but this particular aspect is nebulous to say the least...

Comment: The documentation is highly outdated and I am currently the sole contributor to QueryDSL. Any contributions to the Javadoc and website are highly appreciated.